# jquery: window.location.reload() doesn't allow to work $.post()

Tags: jquery

look at this script please

```
$("#change").click(function()
 {
  var val = $("#new_title").val();
  if(val == '')
  {
   alert("Նշեք խնդրեմ անունը");
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   $.post
   (
    "change_title.php",
    {id: id, lang: lang, val: val}
   );

         window.location.reload();
  }
 });
```

where `id` and `lang` are global variables.

in change_title.php i'm uploading the table.

i want to show changes after editing, so i use  `window.location.reload();` function, but it doesn't work. if i delete `window.location.reload();` function, it works fine.

what is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to run it after the `$.post()` completes, like this:

```
$.post("change_title.php",
       {id: id, lang: lang, val: val},
       function() {window.location.reload(); });
```

Without doing this as the callback to [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) (this runs when it completes), the window is leaving the page *before* the POST completes.  If you don't need to do anything else in that function, you can shorten it down to:

```
$.post("change_title.php",
       {id: id, lang: lang, val: val},
       window.location.reload);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a timeout on `window.location.reload` or use a callback function. The post isn't being given enough time to be sent.

Comment: Timeout is never a good idea in place of a callback function.  There's no guarantee that the server will respond before the time-frame allotted to the timeout.