# Why is jQuery not getting the returned json info from my ColdFusion CFC in this code?

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I have a CFC that cycles through a folder and deletes any files in said folder, sort of a 'clean-up' function after an image is uploaded and saved. In that same CFC I have a function that updates text in a database. Bot functions are fired through a jQuery post. The text function returns some a confirmation to my jQuery function, no problem.

But, the clean-up function isn't returning data to my page. Can anyone see an obvious error in my coding that would keep the clean-up function from returning data to my page and firing the confirmation?

I know the CFC is working because the files are deleted from the folder but it's simply not returning a 'valid' response.

Here's the jQuery:

```
function rebinder(deleteImages){
    $('.editingFormField').attr('value', '');
    if ($('.edit').hasClass('selected')){
        $('.edit').removeClass('selected');
    }
    $('#imagePreview').attr('src', '');
    $('#et').dialog('close');
    $('#ei').dialog('close');
    if (deleteImages == 'yes'){
        $.post("cfc/engine.cfc?method=clearImages&returnformat=json", 
                    {},
                    function(ret) {
                        //Handle the result
                        alert(ret + "the Return");
                        if(ret == "true") {

                        } else {
                            alert("There was an error in the processing (files_no_del)");
                        }
                    });
        $.post("cfc/engine.cfc?method=clearThumbs&returnformat=json", 
                    {},
                    function(ret2) {
                        //Handle the result
                        if(ret2 == "true") {

                        } else {
                            alert("There was an error in the processing (thumbs_no_del)");
                        }
                    });
    }
    location.reload();
};
```

And the CFC:

```
<cffunction name="clearImages" access="remote" output="false" returntype="boolean">
<cfset var deleteConfirm = "true">
<!--- Read Holding Directory --->
<cfdirectory
    action="list"
    directory="#destdir#"
    recurse="true"
    listinfo="name"
    name="qFile"
    />
  <!--- Loop through file query and delete files --->

<cfloop query="qFile">
<cffile action="delete" file="#destdir#/#qFile.name#">
</cfloop>
<cfreturn deleteConfirm>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what's returned from the ajax call using a tool like Firebug?

Comment: Yes. The alert fires but there's no information, just the info I have hard coded into it and Firebug shows no response. Additionally, Firebug shows that the function keeps running. It's like there is an empty return for some reason.

Comment: Simplify your cfc: take out the `cfdirectory` call, take out the loop. Make it just `<cfreturn true>`. Now what happens?

Comment: Same thing... I just gutted the cfc and it's giving me the same (lack of) response in Firebug and still fires my else statement.

Comment: See if you can put the AJAX URL in your browser and what you get back: http://yourserver/cfc/engine.cfc?method=clearImages&returnformat=json  What should happen is that you get back the text.  Also, add an alert("ret is of type " + typeof(ret)) to see what the type of ret is.  Since your alert is firing, you are getting a response and a 200 back from your AJAX request.

Comment: Crazy thought -- your URL looks relative, so I'm guessing this is not a Same Origin Policy issue. Only mentioning it because the "no response in Firefox" thing is a typical symptom.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what that is, Ken. When I try what Tony recommended it returned 'true'. I tried changing the CFC to returntype struct and created a structNew with the "true" as part of the struct (deleteConfirm.r = "true") and it gave me bac a beautifully formatted json response.

Comment: Same Origin Policy is when a page at aaa.example.com is prevented from making an ajax call to bbb.example.com (or somethingelse.com). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @Tony: the return if of type 'string'

Comment: Thank you, Ken. I'm operating in a session.loggedin environment but it's all within the same directory...

Comment: I figured something out. When I remove the location.reload from the function, it all works fine. There must be something with the reload happening before the post receives it's data back from the CFC. Anyone care to comment here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fully functional except for the placement of `location.reload();` Once I moved the reload command into the section of my code that fires when it hears back from the CFC, it worked fine. Nick Craver covered the problem in this post: [jQuery window reload doesn't allow to work post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085856/jquery-window-location-reload-doesnt-allow-to-work-post).

It's worth mentioning that Tony's and Ken's comments also helped in diagnosing the problem. Running the post URL did confirm that the AJAX magic was happening as planned.

Here's the revised code that works:

```
function rebinder(deleteImages){
    $('.editingFormField').attr('value', '');
    if ($('.edit').hasClass('selected')){
        $('.edit').removeClass('selected');
    }
    $('#et').dialog('close');
    $('#ei').dialog('close');
    $('#imagePreview').attr('src', '');
    if (deleteImages == 'yes'){
        $.post("cfc/engine.cfc?method=clearImages&returnformat=json", 
                    {},
                    function(ret) {
                        //Handle the result
                        if(ret == "true") {
                            location.reload();

                        } else {
                            alert("There was an error in the processing (files_no_del)");
                        }
                    });
    } else {
        location.reload();
    }
};
```

The only real change I made was to consolidate my CFC a little. Instead of running two methods to clean out two folders I've boiled it down to one 'clean-up' method that empties both folders.

Answer (score 0):

I have just sneaked through your code, can you use $.getJSON() function to make a call to CFC, you can mention the method that you want to invoke and optionally pass arguments to the method.

```
$.getJSON('Some.cfc', {method: 'fetchImapStartMessages', arg1: 'Hello',
    returnformat: 'json' },
  function(returndata) {
    //some code here that renders the data
  }
});
```

and make sure you set attributes returnformat = "JSON" access="remote" in your CFC method. when the data is returned from CFC method make sure you use serializeJSON(returndata). Does this help?

Comment: The URL specified in combination with the access="remote" in the CFC is sufficient to make sure that it sends back JSON data.  Using the post variables is just an alternative method of achieving the same result.

Comment: Ofeargall is changing data on his server -- it's not an "idempotent" transaction, so `POST` is generally advised over `GET`.

Comment: I've implemented this code and I still get an empty return from my CFC. The alert simply says 'null'.

Comment: @Tony, Ken, I thought the same thing but gave it a try anyway. I know that with my CFC all I ned to do is specify the returntype in my url string to the cfc method.